# Write an ideal as an intersection of maximal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Write
> $$
> I = (x^2+2y^2-2,x^2+xy+y^2-2) \subset \mathbb{R}[x,y]
> $$
> as an intersection of maximal ideals.

I have used the Gröbner basis and I found that the zeros of $I$ are equal to $(\sqrt2,0)$ and $(-\sqrt2,0)$ so I know that
$$
I \subset (x-\sqrt2,y) \cap (x+\sqrt2,y).
$$
I don't know how I can continue. Maybe if I could prove that $\sqrt{I} = I$ then $I  =(x-\sqrt2,y) \cap (x+\sqrt2,y)$ will hold, but how I can prove $\sqrt{I} = I$ in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a minimal prime over $I$. Then  $x^2+2y^2-2,x^2+xy+y^2-2\in P$. It follows that their difference $y^2-xy$ belongs to $P$. Since $P$ is prime we have $y\in P$ or $y-x\in P$.
In the first case $x^2-2\in P$. There are two subcases: $x-\sqrt 2\in P$ or $x+\sqrt 2\in P$. We thus get two minimal primes over $I$, the ones you already found: $(x\pm\sqrt 2,y)$.
In the second case we get $3x^2-2\in P$. Again there are two subcases: $x-\sqrt{\frac23}\in P$ or $x+\sqrt{\frac23}\in P$. We thus get another two minimal primes over $I$: $(x\pm\sqrt{\frac23},y-x)$.

It follows that $\sqrt I$ is an intersection of four prime (actually maximal) ideals.

Now let us prove that $I$ is radical, which is equivalent to $\mathbb R[x,y]/I$ reduced. In order to show this one can use, e.g., [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4043778/121097). This means that we have to show that $\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}/I\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}$ (and another three rings) is a domain. It is easily seen that this quotient ring is in fact a field. Notice that $I\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}$ contains $y(y-x)$ and since $y-x\notin(x-\sqrt 2,y)$ it is invertible in the localization. Then $y\in I\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}$ and we can write $I\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}=(I,y)\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}$. But $(I,y)=(x^2-2,y)$. As above, we notice that $x+\sqrt2\notin(x-\sqrt 2,y)$ and hence it is invertible in the localization. Thus we get $I\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}=(x-\sqrt 2,y)\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}$, and the factor ring $\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}/I\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x-\sqrt 2,y)}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. We proceed the same way for the other three maximal ideals.

Comment: One can also use the $(R_0)$ and $(S_1)$ characterization of reducedness. Since $\dim R/I=0$, $(S_1)$ is trivially satisfied, while $(R_0)$ means that the localizations at maximal ideals are fields, which is exactly what I showed.

Comment: Informally, once you've found four distinct intersections of the conics, that accounts for all the possible intersections allowed by Bezout's theorem, implying that none of the intersections can have multiplicity greater than 1.  Which should imply the reducedness of the intersection ideal.  I'm a bit rusty on how you'd formalize that (especially given that this is over $\mathbb{R}$ as opposed to over an algebraically complete field like $\mathbb{C}$).